# Is WP API going to be around in the long term?

Tags: wp-api

I am a web app developer who wants to use Wordpress as a content system, and need to access that content using an API. As a newcomer, reading about WP API, this seemed like the ideal solution. But before I dive in, I want to be sure that the technology I am using will be supported in the long term. What concerns me is that in Summer 2014, the people developing WP API were "committed" to having it included in Wordpress 4.1 http://wordpress.tv/2014/07/06/rachel-baker-put-your-content-to-rest-with-wp-api/
However, as far as I know, we are now up to 4.2.2, and it seems as if WP API is not part of the core product? Or if it is, that isn't clear in the documentation.
Does anyone have an idea of why this has not happened, an whether the WP API is the right tool to use?
thanks

Comment: This is not really the place to ask about third party products, however, my opinion is that you can do anything you need via the Core AJAX API.

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the core product now (Year 2019).

Answer (score 0):

Before wp-api goes into core it has to compete with a number of other possible additions.  That is not a vote against the plugin, just what is happening in the world of WordPress.

If you look at http://v2.wp-api.org/ you see they are working hard on a version 2 of the API.

I don't see any point in speculating when or if it will go into core - I have been using it for over a year now for users on a mobile app and am in the process of doing a web version with angular.js (waiting for v2 of angular before releasing).